# AngularUI Datepicker resets time on the ngModel

Tags: coffeescript, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got the AngularUI Datepicker hooked up and it works well enough except that when you select a different date on the calender, it resets the time portion of the ISO date attached to it via the ngModel attribute. How can I set it up so it keeps the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by fleshing it out in a directive.

```
input(ng-model="event.date_started", j-datepicker)
div(ng-model="event.date_started", j-datepicker)
```

---

```
.directive 'jDatepicker', ->
    require: 'ngModel'
    link: (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) ->
        # check if elem is an input so when the input
        # gains focus it doesn't spawn another calender
        if not elem.is('input')
            elem.datepicker
                onSelect: (dateText) ->
                    # get the original ISO date and new date
                    oldDate = new Date ngModel.$modelValue
                    newDate = new Date dateText

                    # set the new month and day onto the original ISO date
                    oldDate.setUTCMonth newDate.getUTCMonth()
                    oldDate.setUTCDate newDate.getUTCDate()

                    scope.$apply () ->
                        # update the model with the new info
                        ngModel.$setViewValue oldDate.toISOString()

        ngModel.$render = () ->
            date = new Date ngModel.$viewValue

            # set the default highlighted date on the calender
            elem.datepicker 'setDate', date

            # this renders the date value on the 
            # input element in the format I want
            elem.val date.toDateString()
```